# How can I connect to two separate routers (one via wifi for Internet and one via LAN for networked drives) and still get Internet service?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, lan

I live in a small hotel that provides WIFI Internet service. I have 3 - 2TB Network hard drives I also want access to. I have a Cisco E2000 Wireless Router that they are connected to. For the past 3 months I have jumped the connection back and forth as needed (i.e. Internet to Hard Drives) because I can't seem to connect to both at once properly.

I tried connecting my Cisco Router via LAN cable and wirelessly to the Hotel WIFI. They both appear in my network connections but whenever the LAN cable is plugged in, the internet is gone. I get a DNS error every time. When I pull the cable, the internet comes right back up. Very frustrating. I'm using a laptop with WIN 7. Is there a configuration change I can make to the LAN connection that will prevent this?

Comment: To simultaneously connect to two different wireless SSIDs you would need two radios in your device.   But realistically wireless access to storage is going to be slow and horrible, so explore wired connectivity to those resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your two networks are on different subnets, or in other words the IP address ranges are different.  If  your router providing Internet access gives you an IP address in the `192.168.1.X` range, setup your LAN router to provide addresses from a different range (say `192.168.2.X` assuming a netmask of `255.255.255.0`).

Comment: I'd say give the private LAN an uncommon private address space like `192.168.50.0/24` or `172.16.1.0/24`, and then make sure that the local router is not trying to pass itself off as a default gateway.

Comment: I plugged in the new subnet and netmask. The internet is up but access to the local router is not working. What should I put in the section for default gateway?

Comment: Disregard. I figured it out. I changed the default IP on the router itself. I had been trying to do it thru windows. Thanks heavyd!!